# AppDomain Evidence has no Zone?

Tags: c#, .net

What is controlling the Evidence of the current app domain?

```
var evidence = Thread.GetDomain().Evidence;
```

What controls if it is null or non-null, and what determines it contents?

When my application queries these host evidence objects from the domain evidence

```
var z = evidence.GetHostEvidence<Zone> 
var p = evidence.GetHostEvidence<Publisher>
var s = evidence.GetHostEvidence<Site>
var n = evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>
var u = evidence.GetHostEvidence<Url>
```

it appears as if they are sometimes all null when executing in some environments. The reason I believe this is an exception thrown inside `IsolatedStorage._GetAccountingInfo(...)`, where by looking at the code in reflector it is clear that this exception will only be thrown if the domain evidence contains null for all of the above host evidence objects. This will cause isolated storage to fail to initialize.

Unfortunately I can't reproduce it on my own system. The Zone value for example will always be a proper value saying "My Computer", so I'm struggling to solve this.

What controls the contents of these values in the default app domain of a windows forms desktop application?

Comment: It is initialized by the CLR host when it creates the primary domain.  Heavy changes in .NET 4 with the introduction of EvidenceBase, so I'd look for unusual hosting scenarios that still use legacy evidence.  Including ClickOnce and in-process side-by-side COM activation.

Comment: Thanks Hans. It is a .NET 4 winforms application deployed through a normal MSI. So the problems occur on a normal execution on a normal machines with .NET4. What is the difference between the evidence of a domain, and that of an assembly? In my assemblies, I expect most evidence to be missing since it isn't strong named.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the culprit was indeed an "unusual deployment scenario" as was suggested by Hans in a comment on my question. We use encryption (enveloping) for a few assemblies, and apparently this tampers with the evidence required by isolated storage.

Answer (score 3):

A similar situation occurs when your code is a [COM object accessed by a native Win32 application](http://rekiwi.blogspot.com/2008/12/unable-to-determine-identity-of-domain.html) (the Default `AppDomain`'s `Evidence` is empty), or when it is loaded and [run inside of the command line version of PowerShell.exe](https://explodingmindslimited.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/openxml-and-powershell/). I ran into this problem when using an OpenXML (specifically [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)) assembly that uses IsolatedStorage when the office document is over a certain file size.

Rather than spinning up another `AppDomain` inside of the default one and dealing with an additional level of Marshaling/Remoting, I prefer to use reflection to muck with the current `AppDomain`'s evidence.

Here's the proof of concept in C#:

```
using System;

namespace AppDomainEvidence
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var initialAppDomainEvidence = System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain().Evidence; // Setting a breakpoint here will let you inspect the current AppDomain's evidence
            try
            {
                var usfdAttempt1 = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForDomain(); // This will fail when the current AppDomain Evidence is instantiated via COM or in PowerShell
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Set breakpoint here to inspect Exception "e"
            }

            // Create a new Evidence that include the MyComputer zone
            var replacementEvidence = new System.Security.Policy.Evidence();
            replacementEvidence.AddHostEvidence(new System.Security.Policy.Zone(System.Security.SecurityZone.MyComputer));

            // Replace the current AppDomain's evidence using reflection
            var currentAppDomain = System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain();
            var securityIdentityField = currentAppDomain.GetType().GetField("_SecurityIdentity", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            securityIdentityField.SetValue(currentAppDomain,replacementEvidence);

            var latestAppDomainEvidence = System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain().Evidence; // Setting a breakpoint here will let you inspect the current AppDomain's evidence

            var usfdAttempt2 = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForDomain(); // This should work
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the workaround I implemented in PowerShell:

```
# This one will fail
$usfd = [System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile]::GetUserStoreForDomain()

# Inspect the current AppDomain's Evidence
[threading.thread]::GetDomain().Evidence


# Modify the current AppDomain's Evidence
$evidence = new-object System.Security.Policy.Evidence
$zone = new-object System.Security.Policy.Zone('MyComputer')
$evidence.AddHost($zone)
$currentAppDomain = [threading.thread]::GetDomain()
$securityIdentityField=$currentAppDomain.GetType().GetField('_SecurityIdentity','Instance,NonPublic')
$securityIdentityField.SetValue($currentAppDomain, $evidence)

# Inspect the current AppDomain's Evidence
[threading.thread]::GetDomain().Evidence

# This one will succeed
$usfd = [System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile]::GetUserStoreForDomain()
```

Comment: Thanks, your post was very helpful. I ran into the same issue (which SpreadsheetLight, which also uses OpenXML). I tried the "spinning up another AppDomain" approach first, which quickly ran out of memory when trying to pass large DataTables over the AppDomain remoting boundary via serialization. Your solution works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks this is amazing! I had a similar issue trying to debug my Office Addin which uses OpenXML. I kept getting the error IsolatedStorageFile Unable to determine the identity of domain. This code fixed my AppDomain and allowed my code to run without errors!