# How to register a database as a DAC from WIX custom action using DacServices?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wix, isolatedstorage, dacpac

**Is it possible to register an existing database as a Data Tier Application using DacServices from a WIX custom action?**

I'm trying to do this by loading a DACPAC with the [DacPackage class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacpackage(v=sql.120).aspx) and then registering it with the [DacServices.Register method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh753483(v=sql.120).aspx).

```
var dacPackage = DacPackage.Load(filePath);
var dacServices = new DacServices(connectionString);
dacServices.Register(
    "databaseName",
    DacSchemaModelStorageType.File,
    "applicationName",
    new Version(1, 0, 0, 0));
```

The code works fine when I run it in a console application, but not when run as a WIX custom action. Instead I get an [IsolatedStorageException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstorageexception(v=vs.110).aspx) with this message:

> unable to determine the identity of domain

The exception documentation seems to indicate that the issue is "missing evidence"

> Isolated storage requires evidence (information about the assembly and its origin) in order to determine the identity of the code and connect it to the correct associated file space. Without this information, isolated storage cannot be used.

I can't figure out what this is or how to control it in my scenario.

The stack trace is very long so I have put it in [this paste bin](http://pastebin.com/dSbk993i).

EDIT:

Here is the CustomAction.config file as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: DTF (managed custom actions) does interesting things behind the scenes to make everything work, it's possible that the .NET environment isn't properly setup for this.  Can you provide your CustomAction.config file?

Comment: @SeanHall I have added the CustomAction.config file to the question.

Answer (score 3):

I filed a bug on this at https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5240.  You can probably work around this by creating your own AppDomain with the required Evidence and running your code in your properly created AppDomain.

Using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176363/appdomain-evidence-has-no-zone), this workaround works for me:

```
// This throws an IsolatedStorageException, since we haven't fixed the evidence yet.
//System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForDomain();

// Create a new Evidence that include the MyComputer zone
var replacementEvidence = new System.Security.Policy.Evidence();
replacementEvidence.AddHostEvidence(new System.Security.Policy.Zone(System.Security.SecurityZone.MyComputer));

// Replace the current AppDomain's evidence using reflection
var currentAppDomain = System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain();
var securityIdentityField = currentAppDomain.GetType().GetField("_SecurityIdentity", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
securityIdentityField.SetValue(currentAppDomain,replacementEvidence);

// Now it works.
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForDomain();
```

Comment: Thanks, subscribed. From your comments and mention of particular source files it seems like a genuine issue so hopefully it will be addressed. Due to us moving on and my unfamiliarity with AppDomains and Evidence we will not be trying the work-around. If somebody else does it would be nice to see how they did it.